# What is wrong with this "proof" about solvable groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I claim that every group that has a proper nontrivial normal subgroup is solvable. The reason being that for a group $G$ if we have a nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ by induction we have that $G/N$ is solvable and that $N$ is solvable. Hence, lifting $G/N$ to a normal tower with each normal factor being abelian, we can combine this with the tower of $N$ to see that $G$ is in fact solvable.

Comment: So $S_n$ is soluble?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Looking at the title, I think the OP already knows it's not true.

Comment: In general, if you think you have a proof that you know must be wrong, because you know a counterexample, then you should be able to find the mistake by going through the proof carefully on that counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Why does $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable groups? I think it's just wrong.

Comment: Just strong induction on the order. Since $N$ is proper $N$ and $G/N$ have order less than $G$ by the inductive hypothesis they are solvable.

Comment: @ntntnt But your induction hypothesis is only that all smaller groups *with a proper nontrivial subgroup* are solvable.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.